# .htaccess regex redirects

Tags: regex, .htaccess

How do I create a regex redirect for my .htaccess file that redirects *anything* that has the letters "haz" in it?

```
Redirect /^haz*/i http://ourcityourstory.com/episode/09/
```

The episode is called "Hazzard Free Farms" so I want to be able to create a .htaccess that will redirect /hazzard /Hazzard-Free-Farms/ /hazzard-free etc, all to the correct URL.

How do I accomplish this? I'd like some regex I can use for every episode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `[NC]` flag in order to ignore case:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^haz http://ourcityourstory.com/episode/09/ [L,NC]
```

If you'd rather stick to mod_alias as opposed to mod_rewrite:

```
RedirectMatch ^/[Hh][Aa][Zz] http://ourcityourstory.com/episode/09/
```

Comment: Thank you very much! THis is *exactly* what I needed for this project and will use in my future projects.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  It will redirect any url that starts with "haz" in the path.

```
RewriteRule ^haz(.*)$ http://ourcityourstory.com/episode/09/
```